# In cosa consisteva un gioco chiamato "soprasotto"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto questa frase:

> Qualche figurina veniva comprata, qualcuna scambiata, qualcuna si vinceva a battimuro, a **soprasotto**, a zigozago.

È chiaro che si sta parlando di giochi di ragazzi. Il significato di "battimuro" si trova facilmente sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/battimuro). Per quanto riguarda il "zigozago", cercando un po' su Google Books, sembra che si trattasse di
lanciare una palla contra un muro, battere le mani avanti e dietro, e poi riprendere la palla. Non ho trovato niente però sul significato di "soprasotto". Qualcuno di voi ne sa qualcosa?

Comment: Non conosco il “soprasotto”, ma ipotizzo che possa essere la variante del “sottomuro” (che è un parente del battimuro) descritta nel *Dizionario dei giochi* di Angiolino e Sidoti e simile al gioco di cui parla @abarisone: “Talvolta ... lo scopo non è quello di raggiungere il muro, ma di sovrapporsi alle figurine già presenti ... In un'ulteriore variante ... non importa se si coprono figurine o meno: se la figurina cade a faccia in giù la si lascia dov'è, se a faccia in su la si recupera conquistandone un'altra di quelle già a terra”.

Comment: Aggiungerei un altro gioco che potrebbe definirsi *soprasotto*: disporre un mucchietto figurine a faccia in giù e, con un colpo di mano opportunamente ripiegata, fare capovolgere quante più figurine possibile.

Answer (score 2):

Dal contesto indicato da Stefano Benni, se non intendo (o ricordo) male **soprasotto** sembra simile ad un gioco che facevo da bambino con le figurine dei calciatori per cui un giocatore lanciava la figurina contro il muro e l'altro diceva sopra o sotto intendendo come la figurina era rivolta quando toccava terra.

Se l'avversario indovinava si teneva la figurina altrimenti il lanciatore ne pescava una a caso dal mazzo dell'altro.

Lo facevamo con i mazzi di figurine doppie che molto spesso ne contenevano di mancanti per gli altri amici.